# JSP equivalent to the PHP include() function?

Tags: php, jsp, include, server-side-includes

How should I include an HTML file into another HTML file, using JSP?

```
<jsp:include page="/include.html"></jsp:include>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? How did it fail?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a couple of options. The first is [`<jsp:include>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref1112.html). The second is [`<c:import>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/import.html). The `c:` tags are JSTL, the [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/).

What's the difference? Primarily `<jsp:include>` inserts the contents of another JSP page within the same JAR relative to the current page whereas `<c:import>` can read in an absolute or relative URL and display those contents on the page, retrieve a `Reader` or store the contents in a variable.

The syntax for both is XML-like so:

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>
```

or

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

**Note:** both can take parameters.

Comment: +1. Looking at the docs, it does appear that <jsp:include> will do what the OP is asking for; however, it does not appear to be completely analogous to PHP's include().  Notably, the included file does not share the same global scope; functions/classes created by the included file won't become available in the including script, etc.  Instead, it executes the included script, and returns the output.

Comment: Where's your vote, Frank? I did the first upvote, but I don't see a second one :)

Comment: Thanks, so the example I have above is the proper syntax?

Comment: @devils-avacado: yes. 
@cletus' edit: the actual difference between `jsp:include` and `c:import` is that the first includes the *source* and that the second includes the *output* (apart from having the possiblity to get it from an external URL).

Comment: @cletus or @BalucC, can I include .html, .shtml, .js, or .css using either method? Excuse my ignorance, I'm completely new to JSP.

Comment: The included document is arbitrary so it could be CSS, Javascript or HTML ie what you could normally have in an HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want the same behavior as PHP include() or `<!--#include file="header.jsp"-->`, with shared the global scope in JSP, use the following command:

```
<%@include file="header.jsp"%>
```

Reference: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943770/variables-in-jsp-pages-with-included-pages)