# Loop foreach var is not visible from jsp inlude

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jspinclude

I have the following jsp

```
           ...  
           <table id="table" class="sortable">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="head">Дата Запроса</td>
                            <td class="head">Сумма Запроса</td>
                            <td class="head">Баланс Владельца</td>
                            <td class="head">Статус Запроса</td>
                            <td class="head">Email</td>
                            <td class="head">-----</td>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="event" items="${events}">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <jsp:useBean id="dateValue" class="java.util.Date"/>
                                    <jsp:setProperty name="dateValue" property="time"
                                                     value="${event.timestamp}"/>
                                    <fmt:formatDate value="${dateValue}"
                                                    pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>${event.amount}</td>
                                <td>${event.sourceUser.userAccounts.iterator().next().currentAmount}</td>
                                <td>${event.status}</td>
                                <td>${event.sourceUser.email}</td>
                                <td><c:if test="${event.status != 'SUCCESS'}">
                                    <input type="button" class="withDraw"
                                           value="подтвердить вывод"/>
                                </c:if>

                                    <div class="edit-holder  adt" id="">

                                        <div class="edit-box">
                                            <div class="title">Подтверждение вывода средств владельцем</div>
                                            <form action="/admin/confirmWithdrawRequest"
                                                  method="post">
                                                <div>
                                                    <input type="hidden" value="${event.id}" name="eventId"/>
                                                    <label>Статус</label>
                                                    <select name="status">
                                                        <c:forEach items="${statuses}" var="status">
                                                            <option <c:if test="${status == event.status}">
                                                                        selected="selected"
                                                                    </c:if>
                                                                    >${status}</option>
                                                        </c:forEach>
                                                    </select>
                                                    <div class="clear"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <label>Email</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="with-draw-input" name="email"
                                                           value="${event.sourceUser.email}"
                                                           readonly/>
                                                    <div class="clear"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <label>Текущий баланс</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="with-draw-input" name="balance"
                                                           value="${event.sourceUser.userAccounts.iterator().next().currentAmount}"
                                                           readonly/>
                                                    <div class="clear"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <label>Сумма запроса</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="with-draw-input" name="email"
                                                           value="${event.amount}"
                                                           readonly/>
                                                    <div class="clear"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <label>Комментарий модератора</label>
                                                    <textarea class="moderationComment"
                                                              name="moderationComment">${event.moderationComment}</textarea>
                                                    <div class="clear"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="сохранить"/>

                                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                            </form>
                                            <div class="close"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    ...
```

Now it is compiles good and I see expected result:
[image]

I want to extract last `td` content to separated jsp like this:

```
<tbody>
                            <c:forEach var="event" items="${events}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <jsp:useBean id="dateValue" class="java.util.Date"/>
                                        <jsp:setProperty name="dateValue" property="time"
                                                         value="${event.timestamp}"/>
                                        <fmt:formatDate value="${dateValue}"
                                                        pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>${event.amount}</td>
                                    <td>${event.sourceUser.userAccounts.iterator().next().currentAmount}</td>
                                    <td>${event.status}</td>
                                    <td>${event.sourceUser.email}</td>
                                    <td><jsp:include page="confirmWithDrawModal.jsp"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                            </tbody>
```

and `confirmWithDrawModal.jsp`:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<c:if test="${event.status != 'SUCCESS'}">
  <input type="button" class="withDraw"
         value="подтвердить вывод"/>
</c:if>

<div class="edit-holder  adt" id="">

  <div class="edit-box">
    <div class="title">Подтверждение вывода средств владельцем</div>
    <form action="/admin/confirmWithdrawRequest"
          method="post">
      <div>
        <input type="hidden" value="${event.id}" name="eventId"/>
        <label>Статус</label>
        <select name="status">
          <c:forEach items="${statuses}" var="status">
            <option <c:if test="${status == event.status}">
              selected="selected"
            </c:if>
                    >${status}</option>
          </c:forEach>
        </select>
        <div class="clear"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="with-draw-input" name="email"
               value="${event.sourceUser.email}"
               readonly/>
        <div class="clear"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Текущий баланс</label>
        <input type="text" class="with-draw-input" name="balance"
               value="${event.sourceUser.userAccounts.iterator().next().currentAmount}"
               readonly/>
        <div class="clear"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Сумма запроса</label>
        <input type="text" class="with-draw-input" name="email"
               value="${event.amount}"
               readonly/>
        <div class="clear"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Комментарий модератора</label>
                                                        <textarea class="moderationComment"
                                                                  name="moderationComment">${event.moderationComment}</textarea>
        <div class="clear"/>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn" value="сохранить"/>

      <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
    <div class="close"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and after this refactoring I see following result:

[image]

As you can see variables is not rendered.

How to fix it?

Comment: The _way_ you include the other JSP matters. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14763794/17300) on _[What's the difference between including files with JSP include directive, JSP include action and using JSP Tag Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14580120/17300)_

Comment: @Stephen P Do you think that jsp:include is wrong for my case?

Comment: Yes... the `<%@include ...>` is the form I think you want.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/943789/17300) to _[Variables in jsp pages with "included" pages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/943770/17300)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `.jsp` file gets translated to a `.java` file, which is compiled and run, providing output that ultimately gets sent to the browser.

When you include another jsp within a jsp *how* those get translated and compiled depends on which form of *include* you use.

`<jsp:include page="incpage.jsp">` translates and compiles *mainpage.jsp* and *incpage.jsp* **separately** and inserts the output of incpage.jsp at the *include* location.  Thinking of this situation, incpage.jsp is *independent* of mainpage.jsp so (naturally) doesn't have access to those variables.

`<%@include file="incpage.jsp">` is more like a *C* `#include` where the contents of incpage.jsp are copied into mainpage.jsp *before* translation and compilation take place.  In this case it doesn't even matter if inpage has a .jsp extension.

If you want the included file to act as part of the main file, as it seems you do, you would use the second form of include — `<%@include ...>`

Answer (score 0):

I have found 2 solutions:

1. use `<%@ include file="confirmWithDrawModal.jsp" %>`
2. use this advise https://stackoverflow.com/a/8003143/2674303

I am not sure which approach better